# rake aborted when running heroku run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku, migration

I did some local migrations on my own database, and when i tried to migrate on heroku, it was givin me a termination:

```
 Multiple migrations have the name CreateUsers
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:978:in `validate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:876:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Ive tried heroku pg:reset DATABASE and migrating again, still gives me this error

Running the database locally seems to be fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: This `Multiple migrations have the name CreateUsers` looks like a very helpful bit of feedback.  Do you have two migrations with the same class name?

Comment: 20140219235208_create_users.rb  
   20140220063644_add_years_to_users.rb
   20131225101255_add_password_digest_to_users.rb
   20131225095857_add_index_to_users_email.rb
20140103210551_add_remember_token_to_users.rb
these are all the migrations

Comment: I said class name, not file name.  Look inside the files: do two of them have `class CreateUsers` at the start?  They all need to have a unique class.

Comment: no they dont. each one has a unique class

Comment: please can you run this in the command line, in your rails project folder, and post the results in an edit to your question?
`tail -n 100 db/migrate/*`

Comment: fixed it with heroku run rake db:schema:load, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`This Multiple migrations have the name CreateUsers` looks like you have two migrations with the same class name `CreateUsers`

Please run all of your `migrations` locally if that are successfully then try to re push in heroku again

hope it will solve your/this problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem this way:
1.check db/migrate folder. You will see at least two files with the same name.
2.delete older files. Use git rm db/migrate/"name of file"
3.push to git

```
$git add -A
$git commit -m ""
$git checkout master
```

4.push up to the remote repository and deploy to Heroku:

```
$ bundle exec rake test
$ git push
$ git push heroku
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```